# CSS children selector (not being able to select all children)

Tags: html, css, beautifulsoup

[image]

This is the image of what I'm trying to scrape using beautiful soup. But whenever I use the code shown below, I only get access to the first child. I am never able to get access to all the children. Can someone help me with this?

```
item = soup.select("ul.items > li")
print(len(item))
```

Comment: Quoting @Kate - Post the code, please. That would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

**The problem can be fixed in 2 steps as follows:**

1. Use ***select_one*** on ***soup*** to get the ***ul***
2. Use ***find_all*** on ***ul*** to fetch all the ***li*** items.

**Working solution:**

```
# File name: soup-demo.py

inputHTML = """
<ul class="items">
<li class="class1">item 1</li>
<li class="class1">item 3</li>
<li class="class1">item 3</li>
</ul>
"""
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
soup = BeautifulSoup(inputHTML, 'html.parser')
itemList = soup.select_one("ul", class_="items")

items = itemList.find_all("li")
print("Found ", len(items), " items")
for item in items:
    print(item)
```

**Output:**

```
$ python3 soup-demo.py 
Found  3  items
<li class="class1">item 1</li>
<li class="class1">item 3</li>
<li class="class1">item 3</li>
```

Comment: However, in the whole web page there are many - <ul class="items"> and there is not only one. So, how do I get all of them and make it work for each of them? I don't know how many there will be in the particular web page.

Comment: If you want to find all the elements, then use select instead of select_one. select_one finds the first match. select finds all matches.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your version is wrong. This is OK.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
html = '''
<ul class="items">
  <li>1</li>
  <li>2</li>
</ul>
'''
soup = BeautifulSoup(html,features="lxml")
item = soup.select('ul.items>li')
print (len(item))
```

There's another solution here

```
from simplified_scrapy.simplified_doc import SimplifiedDoc
html = '''
<ul class="items">
  <li>1</li>
  <li>2</li>
</ul>
'''
doc = SimplifiedDoc(html)
item = doc.selects('ul.items>li')
print(len(item))
```

Here are more examples [here](https://github.com/yiyedata/simplified-scrapy-demo/tree/master/doc_examples)